# How to Stop Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, twitter, apache-spark, streaming, connector

I am working on twitter connector. I want to stop streaming after one minute.
Can anyone give idea ho to do this? 
I tried ssc.awaitTermination(60000). but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `awaitTermination` with a timeout is deprecated:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala#L633

However with either `awaitTermination` or `awaitTerminationOrTimeout` you should follow it with `ssc.stop` to stop the context once the timeout is reached.